# VS code: java error en la clase principal

Tags: java

He estado probando *Java* en **netbeans** y en **VS code**, también

En el primero no tengo problemas para hacer algún programa, en VS code, al momento de ejecutar un programa me lanza el siguiente error:

> Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal App1
> Causado por: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: App1/App1 (wrong name: App1)

este es el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo lo tengo en una carpeta que se llama `App1`

Este error solo me aparece si tuviera el archivo en una carpeta, si lo tengo en el área de trabajo no me lanza ningún error.

¿Qué debo de hacer?

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por motivos de legibilidad, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro, pero creo que Java es muy quisquilloso a la hora de estructurar tu aplicación. La estructura que sigue con Maven es muy característica. Tal vez el fichero .xml que ejecuta el programa intente buscarlo en el directorio src/main/java y no lo encuentre y al tener la clase main en una carpeta que se llama App1 te sale ese error.

En este enlace puedes encontrar información sobre la estructura de la que te hablo, pero seguramente la habrás visto ya en netbeans.
https://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/estructura-basica-de-un-proyecto-con-maven/

Comment: Gracias, lo cheque y ese era el error

Answer (score 2):

Si estas en vs code, elimina el package de la línea numero 1, es muy probable que tu estructura de archivos y paquetes en el mismo folder de espacio de trabajo este mal estructurada.
te comparto este link para más información.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

Comment: Si lo elimino me manda error porque el archivo lo tengo en una carpeta

Answer (score 0):

Encontramos que la ruta puede ser un problema. En MAc si tu proyecto esta en el escritorio, resultó que el nombre muy largo puede ser causa del problema.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/).